# C code to convert endianness?

Tags: c, endianness

I want to convert an unsigned 32-bit integer as follows:

```
Input = 0xdeadbeef

Output = 0xfeebdaed
```

Thank you.

Comment: The example you've given flips the number by 4-bit chunks, not the full 8-bit byte.

Comment: Is this really what you want to do?  You've reversed the nibbles, not the bytes... endianess?

Answer (score 4):

That's **not** an endianness conversion. The output should be `0xEFBEADDE`, not `0xFEEBDAED`. (Only the *bytes* are swapped, and each byte is 2 hexadecimal digits.)

For converting between little- and big-endian, take a look at [_byteswap_ulong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx).

Comment: Or perhaps `htonl` on *nix systems (with the side note that `htonl` will be a no-op on big-endian systems).

Comment: I've found `htobe16`, `htole16`, `le16toh`, `be16toh` and the 32-bit versions to be more useful (and explicit) when writing cross-platform code.  If a given platform doesn't have them, it's easy to map the names to whatever the platform does have.

Comment: @tomlogic: Those don't work on big-endian systems though... and can't you remap `_byteswap_ulong` just as easily? It's just a `#define`...

Comment: `htobe16` and `htole16` work just fine on either big or little endian systems.  On big endian, `htobe16` is a macro that does nothing and `htole16` maps to the byteswap.  On little endian, it's the reverse.  You rarely want to swap the byte order -- it much more likely that you want to convert between host byte order and big or little endian.

Comment: @tomlogic: That means it doesn't do what the OP wants, because it doesn't work on big endian systems. :\

Answer (score 1):

The general process for **nibble reversal** is:

> ((i & 0xF0000000)>>28) | ((i &
>   0xF000000)>>20) | ((i & 0xF00000)>>12)
>   | ..... | ((i & 0xF)<<28)

Mask, shift, or (I hope I got the numbers right):

1. Extract the portion of the number you're interested in by ANDing (&) with a mask.
2. Shift it to it's target location with the >> and << operations.
3. Construct the new value by ORing (|) the pieces together.

If you want to reorder bytes you will mask with 0xFF.  As everyone is saying that's probably what you want and if you're looking for a canned version follow other people's suggestions.